# setRightBarButtonItems doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

I am trying to have 2 buttons on the right of a `UINavigationBar`. Below is the source code. No error but there is no button either. It is a `UIViewController`, not a `UINavigationViewController`

```
let buttonEdit: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
buttonEdit.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
buttonEdit.setImage(UIImage(named:"me44.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
buttonEdit.addTarget(self, action: "rightNavItemEditClick:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
var rightBarButtonItemEdit: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: buttonEdit)

let buttonDelete: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
buttonDelete.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
buttonDelete.setImage(UIImage(named:"me44.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
buttonDelete.addTarget(self, action: "rightNavItemDeleteClick:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

var rightBarButtonItemDelete: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: buttonDelete)

// add multiple right bar button items       
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([rightBarButtonItemDelete, rightBarButtonItemEdit] as [AnyObject], animated: true)

//I also tried code below no luck either
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([rightBarButtonItemDelete, rightBarButtonItemEdit] as [AnyObject], animated: true)
```

Comment: Is it a UIViewController *in* an UINavigationController?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code is just wrong:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(
    [rightBarButtonItemDelete, rightBarButtonItemEdit] as [AnyObject], animated: true)
```

You do not set the navigation controller's `navigationItem`; you set *your* `navigationItem`. Also, the `[AnyObject]` thing is just unnecessary. So:

```
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(
    [rightBarButtonItemDelete, rightBarButtonItemEdit], animated: true)
```

However, note that that works only if your view controller is the child of a UINavigationController. Setting a view controller's `navigationItem` populates a navigation bar automatically only in that situation. If you are *not* in that situation — i.e., if you just have a "loose" navigation bar in your interface — you need to populate your navigation bar *manually* (by setting *its* `navigationItem`).

(Also, note that if you have no `"me44.png"` image, it could be that your code is working but you just aren't *seeing* anything.)

Comment: thanks to your info I used self.navBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItems = [rightBarButtonItemDelete, rightBarButtonItemEdit]
and it worked.

Comment: Excellent. What most people do, though, is use a UINavigationController _even if there isn't going to be any navigation_. That way, you can use the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

Despite all indicated previously, it's possible that you don't see the added button to navigation bar. For Swift 3, try this in the **AppDelegate class** (pay attention to **topItem**):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow()
    window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController())

    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addTodo))
    navigationVC.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = addButton

    window?.rootViewController = navigationVC
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```